# How to find the start and end offset of a range when the selection is across multiple HTML tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to come up with a jquery script that will help to find out the following variables

**startNodeIndex
startOffset
endNodeIndex
endOffset  **

I can do it if the selection is in a single HTML tag only, but i want to figure out when users selects across multiple tags (for example two parah `<p>` tags). This is what I have till now. I want to add a span around this range.

```
if (typeof window.getSelection != 'undefined') {
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
 var startNode = range.startContainer, endNode = range.endContainer;

   var startOffset = range.startOffset;
        var endOffset = startOffset + range.toString().length - 1;

        console.log("Selection starts at: " + startOffset);
        console.log("Selection ends at: " + endOffset);
    }
```

But this code does not work if the user selects text from more than one element at a time. Can some one share with me how to make is possible to get the above mentioned four values.
Thanks in advance